# How to create authentication on android from the password field hashed by cakephp

Tags: php, android, mysql, cakephp, hash

I have database (MySQL) and the password field is hashed in cakephp 2 salt.
Now I'm creating android application that get the data from my web database.

I wonder how can we do auth in android if the password field is the hashed password from cakephp? Can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would never download the password from the db to the client.  You send the username/password from the client to the server.  The server will then authenticate you (by salting/hashing the password and checking if they match) and sending back a token to use for future requests

Comment: Thank you! i can do that